# Twilio outbound call passing data back to site .net

Tags: asp.net, twilio

I am relatively new to Twilio, although it seems like an awesome application!

Basically what I need to accomplish is the following:

I have a .net application that generates an outgoing call and prompts the person for a numeric input - how do I get that input (just numbers of course) back into my .aspx page to deal with it further? For instance, if it said "enter your age" and then I wanted the .aspx page to display their age in a label.

I currently have a button on a page that sends goes to an .ashx file that runs the twiml code, which ends in

```
    context.Response.Write(twiml.ToString());
    context.Response.End();`
```

and the type is "text/xml"

Maybe I am stupid and totally missing the point, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to accomplish this.

Thank you so much in advance!

Syd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What you're looking for is the [Gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb. With that you can get the digits entered on a call. So when a call comes in, you could for example return TwiML as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather timeout="10" finishOnKey="*">
        <Say>Please enter your pin number and then press star.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

If you want that information to get to your server, you could use actions as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="/process_gather.aspx" method="GET">
        <Say>
            Please enter your age and press star on your keypad.
        </Say>
    </Gather>
    <Say>We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!</Say>
</Response>
```

Twilio will then make a POST request to your server with those digits and you can do whatever you like with that.

Generating TwiML in .NET MVC for example could be accomplished as follows:

```
public ActionResult MainMenu()
{
    var response = new TwilioResponse();

    response.BeginGather(new {
    action = "/process_gather.aspx", numDigits = "2" });
    response.Say("Please enter your age");
    response.EndGather();
    response.Hangup();

    return TwiML(response);
}
```

Also, have a look at this [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/02/twilio-for-net-developers-part-7-sms-voice-application-flows-using-asp-net-mvc.html) to read about call flows in .NET using Twilio.

Hope that helps you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get that and I put in my aspx page as the action, and when the call goes through, after I put in digits to be gathered it hangs up but the .aspx page doesn't refresh or anything. how can I make sure/double check the data is getting back to the page and make it refresh?

Comment: right now I have: twiml.BeginGather(new {
                    action = "http://sydheller.com/default.aspx",
                    numDigits = "1" });
                twiml.Say("Please enter your PIN");
                twiml.EndGather();
                twiml.Say("Thank You");
                twiml.Hangup();

Comment: I'm using Webforms, but I suppose I could switch to mvc if I had to

Comment: You're doing it right, but the logic to refresh the page will need to be written by you. Twilio will not refresh that page for you as it's doing it in a separate request. I'd suggest storing the information from Twilio on a database, and then getting it back via an Ajax request or something like that. That is beyond this question though.

Comment: Yeah, I then my next question would be how to send it from Twilio to a database. Also though, I don't particularly want to create another database entry to store the response from each phone call if I don't have to. I hope there is some logic that can be written on my .aspx page to handle the request, which I believe is a POST request, but I am  just not exactly sure how to implement that.

Comment: You could use your existing database and just store the extra data you get from the user (have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). 

Like I said, your question is now beyond what Twilio can/can't do as the original question has now been answered.

I suggest marking this question as answered and asking a new question if you still need some help with storing on the database.